# What range of characters can PHP's openssl_encrypt() output using AES-256-cbc?

Tags: php, encryption

I'm using PHP's openssl_encrypt(), and I was wondering what the set of all possible output characters is when the encryption method is AES-256-cbc? Thanks for any help you can provide!

- Rohan

Answer (score 3):

According to the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-encrypt.php):

> returns a raw or base64 encoded string

This is determined by the 4th parameter: $raw_output

> Setting to TRUE will return as raw output data, otherwise the return value is base64 encoded.

Therefore, if you set $raw_output to TRUE, then raw binary is returned, meaning any character is possible. If you don't set it (or set it to false), then a [base64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) string is returned, meaning the possible characters are A-Z, a-z, 0-9, +, / and =.